# Weird "invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed" exception in ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

The case:

in web config:

```
 MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

There are two seperate connections in Web Request:

```
public IDbConnection GetOpenConnection()
    {
        var connection = ConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection();
        return connection;
    }

using (var con = GetOpenConnection())
{
    var users = con.Select<User>(@"Select * from User (nolock)");
} 

using (var con = GetOpenConnection())
{
    var classrooms= con.Select<Classroom>(@"Select * from Classroom (nolock)");
}
```

But If I use new IDbConnection Extensions there is random "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed" exception.

And this is  suspected ServiceStack.OrmLite method:

```
public static T Exec<T>(this IDbConnection dbConn, Func<IDbCommand, T> filter)
    {
        var holdProvider = OrmLiteConfig.TSDialectProvider;
        try
        {
            var ormLiteDbConn = dbConn as OrmLiteConnection;
            if (ormLiteDbConn != null)
                OrmLiteConfig.TSDialectProvider = ormLiteDbConn.Factory.DialectProvider;

            using (var dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand())
            {
                dbCmd.Transaction = OrmLiteConfig.CurrentTransaction;

                var ret = filter(dbCmd);
                LastCommandText = dbCmd.CommandText;
                return ret;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            OrmLiteConfig.TSDialectProvider = holdProvider;
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

I'm getting same error from ConvertToList in OrmLiteUtilExtensions.

**UPDATE AFTER 6 YEARS**

My question is too old.  I don't think the problem is still continuing, most probably this question is outdated. But there is no option to close the question because of "outdate". I think, SO must add "outdated" option to close reason.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the code snippet above causes the exception, or is it when you do something else? You state "But if I use new IDbConnection Extensions..." This leads me to believe that your error occurs when you do something other than the snippet you provided. How are you calling the `Exec` extension method?

Comment: It was 2012, I don't think the problem is still continuing, most probably this question is outdated.